# I'm unable to map drift columns in Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I can't map drift my columns in ADF data flow. I'm able to manually, but this isn't possible as I have 1020 columns. File is .csv

I see a message: 'This drifted column is not in the source schema and therefore can only be referenced with pattern matching expressions'

I was hoping to have a map drifted data flow from my source data.

Comment: Could you please add any picture of your error with a sample input and expected result?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With > 1k columns, you should consider NOT mapping those columns. Just use column patterns inside your transformation expressions to access columns. Otherwise, ADF will have to materialize the entire 1k+ columns as a physical projection.